# Can not show some image in react naitve

Tags: react-native

I`m New programmer.

I want to show some image in react-native but I can't.
my Url is working fine in browser and show image. Another Url is working fine in my Image Component,
but whenever I want to load this Image, It`s failed Load 
[this Image](https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/81029992_467176754190207_4901390856020107347_n.jpg?_nc_cat=102&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=H6AtyKWx0U0AX95qU2t&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=7ad928f323a8c64e81a4e8abe3dd5142&oe=5E9F51E6)

this image is shown when I connected to **wifi**, but whenever I connected to **mobile data**, not show.

my code is here:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Image
      style={{ resizeMode: 'cover', width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
      source={{
        uri:
          'https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/81029992_467176754190207_4901390856020107347_n.jpg?_nc_cat=102&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=H6AtyKWx0U0AX95qU2t&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=7ad928f323a8c64e81a4e8abe3dd5142&oe=5E9F51E6',
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

Can Any One Help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to display the same image in one of my react-native projects. I am able to display it you can check attached image for the same. It took some time to display but it displayed at last.

You can try onError to see if you are getting any error or not.

[image: Facebook Image]

```js
<Image
  onError={e => {
    let tempData = { ...this.state.userData }
    tempData.imageUri = ''
    this.setState({ userData: tempData })
  }}
  style={ProfileStyle.profileImageStyle}
  borderRadius={50}
  source={
    { uri: 'https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/81029992_467176754190207_4901390856020107347_n.jpg?_nc_cat=102&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=H6AtyKWx0U0AX95qU2t&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=7ad928f323a8c64e81a4e8abe3dd5142&oe=5E9F51E6' }}
  defaultSource={constant.completeProfile.userPlaceHolder}
/>
```

Comment: tnx, @Rajan I think my problem is with Data Mobile. Because it works properly with WiFi and displays the image.

Comment: Great. Still, you can use onError() to handle any kind of error.